# get server time using linq to sql

Tags: c#, linq, selenium-webdriver

How to get db server time using linq in selenium C# without using add and substract. Date.TimeNow is giving system time (EST) but the server is with different time (CST). As per instructions I am not supposed to use Add or substraction. Could someone help me with this.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Why are you using Linq to SQL, but not querying a database? What are you trying to add or subtract from? Do you mean DateTime.Now rather than Date.TimeNow?

Comment: simple answer: you can't. Long answer: No you cannot. Unless the server is exposing an api or putting it on he webpage you can't access the server directly

Answer (score 0):

```
 DateTime serverTime = DateTime.Now; // current Time
 DateTime utcTime = serverTime.ToUniversalTime; // convert it to Utc

 TimeZoneInfo timezoneinfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("India Standard Time");
 DateTime localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcTime, timezoneinfo ); // convert from utc to local.
```